# How to describe this figure clearly? 2 dimensional feature vector?

Tags: word-usage, expressions

This [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/53366/74719) is discussing the perceptron model.

[image]

x_1 and x_2 are x axis and y axis respectively.

should I call this figure 2-variable function or 2 dimensional feature vector, or something else?

Comment: I would call it a two-feature classification, if you look for a short caption or title.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't seem to be related to English per se, but to domain-specific terminology.